# Book Recommendations on Options Derivatives

Tags: options, derivatives, books

I want to learn about Options Derivatives and am looking for an introductory (as much as possible) book to start with. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

John C. Hull: Options, Futures and Other Derivatives

Comment: For an introduction, I recommend an edition of Hull from a *long time ago*, when the book was shorter and easier. For example the Third Edition from 1998, or the Second Edition. The current edition is the 10th and is a https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Doorstopper

Answer (score 0):

Interest Rate Models: Theory and Practice: With Smile, Inflation and Credit

https://www.amazon.fr/Interest-Rate-Models-Practice-Inflation/dp/3662517434

In my opinion studying fixed income derivatives gives you far more insight than just studying equity derivatives. Plus this one gives you market data which allows you to implement yourself some models which trains you even more beacause you'll face real world problems.

Cheers